# Unable to query MSSQL table by datetime column with nodejs-mssql

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, datetime

I have a table in MSSQL database:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    ID int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
    UserID int NULL,
    Starttime datetime NULL
);
ALTER TABLE Test ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Test PRIMARY KEY (ID);

INSERT INTO Test (UserID, Starttime) VALUES (1, '2019-01-01 01:01:01.000');
```

and I'm trying to use NodeJS [mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) package to query that table with `UserID` and `Starttime` parameters which I fetch from remote location.

`UserID` parameter in response from remote location is an integer, and `Starttime` is an encoded URI string - `2019-01-01T01%3A01%3A01`.

If I query the table with the hardcoded `Starttime` values, everything works fine, but when I try to use `Starttime` from remote response and decode it with `decodeURIComponent()`, my query responds with 0 results:

```
const userID = response.user_id;  // userID -> 1
const dateFromResponse = response.start_time;  // dateFromResponse -> '2019-01-01T01%3A01%3A01'
const start1 = new Date('2019-01-01T01:01:01');
const start2 = new Date(decodeURIComponent(dateFromResponse));
// (decodeURIComponent(dateFromResponse) === '2019-01-01T01:01:01') ---> true
// (start1.valueOf() === start2.valueOf()) ---> true
// (start1.toISOString() === start2.toISOString()) ---> true

const test = await mssqlRequest
  .input('UserID', sql.Int, userID)
  .input('Starttime', sql.DateTime2, start1)
  .query('SELECT * FROM Test WHERE UserID = @UserID AND Starttime = @Starttime');
const l = test.recordset.length;  // results in 1


const test2 = await mssqlRequest
  .input('UserID', sql.Int, userID)
  .input('Starttime', sql.DateTime2, start2)
  .query('SELECT * FROM Test WHERE UserID = @UserID AND Starttime = @Starttime');
const l2 = test2.recordset.length;  // results in 0
```

Why is this happening and how should I parse the string from response in order to make my query work?

Comment: Can you try to run the same, and just switch `start1` and `start2` in `input(...`)? So the `start2` runs first

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, results are exactly the same, if I use `start1` query results as expected, `start2` doesn't.